# How to make an XP machine on a network not able to access internet?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

If I have an XP machine on a network, how can I make it so the machine can access other machines on the network but not access the internet?

Comment: shouldn't manually setting up the network settings and in the process setting the DNS servers to a non-existent address (0.0.0.0?) work? or is my understanding of the function of a DNS server when accessing local computers flawed (that understanding being that they play little to no role)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a firewall to take care of this. But if you're sure the user of this computer is not going to try to break out, there's also an easier option: invalidate or remove the default gateway, which is needed for any traffic outside of the local subnet.

Do not mess with the dns servers as xantec suggests, that could break lan-functions as well, such as printing to a network-printer or active directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the hosts file in `C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/Etc`.

For example if you wanted to block www.facebook.com, just add the following line to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    www.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If your router allows it you can block access to port 80 and 443 for the IP of the computer you want to disallow. You could also use IPsec to block the traffic here is a [guide](http://www.petri.co.il/block_web_browsing_with_ipsec.htm) to setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a firewall to block all outgoing and incoming traffic on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an incorrect DNS server, that should do it. The LAN will still work.